# Immutable Collection Treated as Mutable. Cannot use Collections.max

Tags: kotlin, collections, android-camera, android-camera2

I am working with Camera2 API, and I am trying to retrieve the largest available image size. I want to use Collections.max. I have tried to write this code in Java, and it works fine.

JAVA Ex-

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
```

However, the Kotlin equivalent has an issue with the `Collections.max` operation.

Kotlin Ex-

```
val characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)

                val map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP
                ) ?: continue

    // for still image captures, we use the largest available size
                    val largest = Collections.max(
                        listOf(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                        CompareSizesByArea()
                    )
```

The error says,

> None of the following substitutions ((MutableCollection<out
> Array<(out) Size!>!>..Collection<Array<(out) Size!>!>?),Comparator<in
> Array<(out) Size!>!>!) ((MutableCollection<out
> Size!>..Collection<Size!>?),Comparator<in Size!>!) can be applied to
> (List<Array<(out) Size!>!>,CompareSizesByArea)

I am not sure how to correct my code. I can use Collections.max in other instances, such as

```
val test = listOf(1,2,3,4,3,2,1)
Collections.max(test)
```

The issue is the map of output sizes??

Comment: have you tried .maxBy ?

Comment: Yeah for future reference, ``maxBy`` is a thing, which I always need to remind myself after going "why isn't ``max`` working on this ``Comparable``??" for ten minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()`, as you used in your Java code, converts an array to a `List`. So you have a `List<Size>`.

`listOf()`, as you used in your Kotlin code, creates a list of the items you pass to it. In this case, you pass a single item to it, an array. So you are creating a `List<Array<Size>>` with a single object in it, the array of sizes.

The equivalent way to do `Arrays.asList()` in Kotlin is to simply call `.asList()` on the array:

```
val largest = Collections.max(
        map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG).asList(),
        CompareSizesByArea()
    )
```

But if you're going to do it purely in Kotlin, you can skip the `Collections` function and do this more simply:

```
val largest = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG).maxBy { it.width * it.height }
```

Comment: Very good explanation! This is working now. Thank you